# Question Concerning the classification of 1-manifolds

Tags: differential-topology

I am having trouble proving the following statement used in proving the classification of 1-manifolds.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Let $L$ be a subset of $X$ diffeomorphic to an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, where dim $X=1.$ Then the closure Cl$(L)$ contains at most two points not in L.

Comment: Is $X$ a manifold?

Comment: Yes, $X$ is a 1-manifold.